# List the open sets containing the positive number $6$

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ be the class of subsets of $\mathbb N$ consisting of the empty set. All subsets of $\mathbb N$ of the form $E_n = \{n,n+1,n+2,\dots\}$ with $n$ being an element of $\mathbb N$.

List the open sets containing the positive number $6$.

I am sorry for the bad formatting. I am still learning how to do that. This problem seems like a really easy one but I keep getting stuck for some reason. I was thinking that it’ll just be $\{n\leq 6\leq k\}$ where $n,k\in\mathbb N$ and $n>0$. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Assuming the usual topology on $\mathbb R$, then $\mathbb N$ has no open subsets containing 6. Indeed, any non-empty open subsets of $\mathbb R$ are uncountable.

Comment: What do you mean by "The class of all subsets of N consisting of $0$?"  What does the second sentence mean?  It isn't really a sentence, just part part of one.  I can't tell what you are asking.  Please try to state what are the points of the space, and what are the open sets, more clearly.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the sets of the form $E_n$ are open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the space is $X=\Bbb N$ with the topology $\mathcal{T}$ generated by all sets $E_n$ (we only need to add $\emptyset$ to get a topology, so we're almost there; maybe this is what the first two sentences meant to say, namely that $\mathcal{T}=\{\emptyset\} \cup \{E_n| n\in \Bbb N\}$? ).

Then $E_0=\Bbb N, E_1,E_2,E_3,E_4,E_5,E_6$ is a complete list of all open sets that contain $6$ in $\mathcal{T}$.